# Symfony2 - HWIOAuthBundle - Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I have followed bundle [documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/Resources/doc/index.md) configuring the `HWIOAuthBundle` for facebook. Then I followed [this](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/Resources/doc/bonus/facebook-connect.md) example for facebook login button display and it seems to be working, but it is not completed. I am stuck and don't know what to do next. After I press facebook login button and login to facebook I get error:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/sign-in/check-facebook". The route is wrongly configured.
```

config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: hwi_oauth
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:           facebook
            client_id:      "%facebook_client_id%"
            client_secret:  "%facebook_client_secret%"
            scope:          email
            options:
                display:    popup
                auth_type:  rerequest
                csrf:       true
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    hwi_oauth:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook: /sign-in/check-facebook
            login_path:   /sign-in
            failure_path: /sign-in
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: oauth_user_provider
```

routing.yml

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /sign-in

facebook_login:
    path: /sign-in/check-facebook
```

So what is this `/sign-in/check-facebook` needed for? Why my application can't find it? Do I have to create the controller for it?

In documentation [here](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/Resources/doc/internals/response_object_and_paths.md) it is said to that information can be get through response object, but where do I write this code?

Comment: After the unnecessary waste of time, I propose to solve the connection with official Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `security.yml`. Do you have any other firewalls that the application might be processing before your `hwi_oauth` firewall? It seems that @jkuri had that problem here: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/781#issuecomment-100468744

His answer:

> To answer my own question... a added firewall olta_portal before main firewall... don't know where was the problem, maybe because of the same pattern ^/ in both firewalls. Working now.

I've struggled with this issue before, too! One other sanity check is to do a `php app/console debug:router | grep facebook`, to verify that your route is even registered with the application in the first place.

Comment: That is the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled a lot when configuring HWIOAuthBundle and so when I finally got the configuration right I made sure I never forget it by adding it in a [pretty nice tutorial](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/11/13/symfony2-facebook-google-login/):

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        oauth:
            failure_path: your_path
            login_path: your_path
            check_path: /connect_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            resource_owners:
                facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                google: "/login/check-google"
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: app.provider.oauth
```

The tutorial also explains how to properly setup the `FOSUBUserProvider`, the `UserModel` and how to add the links.